# Hide path derived from parent class

Tags: java, swagger, quarkus

I have a resource class

```java
public class GenericResource{
  @POST
  @Operation(summary = "Create new element", description = "Create a new element by body")
  public Response post(@RequestBody(description = "Element to create", required = true)     ClassRequestEntity data) throws Exception {
    ....
  }
}
```

I have the child class that extend this. In all my classes, I only extend and use the method, in one case I must not have this method.
So I tried to do this

```java
public class Info extends GenericResousrce{
  @Operation(hidden = true)
  @Schema(hidden = true)
  @Deprecated
  @Override
  public Response post(@RequestBody(description = "Element to create", required = true)     ClassRequestEntity data) throws Exception {
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("....");
  }
}
```

I want that "post()" method to not be visible on Swagger.

But all my attempts fail. Is there a way to do this?